# Count all columns in a table individually

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to do some data exploration on a table to count all columns and all unique strings in the row individually like the below output:

```
+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
| table_name | column_name | distinct   | count(*) |
|            |             | row_string |          |
+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
| customer   | state       | WA         | 15       |
+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
| customer   | state       | NSW        | 786      |
+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
| customer   | state       | SA         | 51       |
+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
| ...        | ...         | ...        | ...      |
+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
| customer   | zip_code    | 3563       | 33       |
+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
| customer   | zip_code    | 7583       | 52       |
+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
| customer   | zip_code    | 3453       | 553      |
+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
| customer   | zip_code    | 2132       | 211      |
+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
| ...        | ...         | ...        | ...      |
+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
```

I've been doing something like this:

```sql
    select state, count(*)
    from customer
    group by state
    union
    select zip_code, count(*)
    from customer
    group by zip_code
    union
    ...
```

however this is not efficient assuming you have heaps of columns in the table. Is there a more effective way to achieve this?

Comment: Not really. Switching to `UNION ALL` will be more performant, assuming you want separate counts for when 2 columns have the same value. Such a requirement smells of an [XY problem](//xyproblem.info) if I am honest.

Comment: You could, if you really need it, generate such a query quite easily when you look at `sys.tables` and `sys.columns`

Comment: "more effective" in terms of what? Ease of development or performance? A generic way of doing this that is quick to change source on would be https://dbfiddle.uk/Oz23fPKl but that won't be efficient performance wise.

Comment: @MartinSmith both. Thanks for sharing your script. This is perfect for development.

Answer (score 0):

*(The below was posted before I looked at the link that Martin Smith posted in the comments above. That approach using XML appears simpler and likely has roughly similar performance.)*

You can try generating dynamic SQL that looks like:

```
select
    cast(N'customer' AS sysname) AS table_name,
    C.column_name,
    C.value,
    count(*) AS [count]
from [customer] T
cross apply (
    values
        (cast(N'state' AS sysname), cast(T.[state] AS nvachar(max)),
        (cast(N'zip_code' AS sysname), cast(T.[zip_code] AS nvachar(max))
) C(column_name, value)
group by column_name, value
```

The `CAST()` operations might be seem like overkill, but they may be necessary to prevent truncation if shorter data is followed by longer data. For some data types like DATETIME or FLOAT, you might want to be more precise in the formatting, perhaps even intentionally limiting excess precision.

When injecting table names and column names into the generated SQL, use `QUOTENAME(...)` and `QUOTENAME(..., '''')` to safely [quote] or 'quote' the injected values.